# How to create list of text which construct by concatenating text and index number

Tags: python, list, text

I have to create a list of text that contain the information which concatenated between text and index number in list. My expected result will be a package that post to front end application. However, my input list was show below

```
list = [[[1, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 3]], [[3, 2]], [[4, 7, 6, 5]]]
```

And my purpose is to organize a list of text by using the above list to complete this format:

```
result =[["No. 1 will swap position with No. 2"], 
         ["No. 2 will swap position with No. 1 Or No.2 will swap position with No.3 "],
         ["No. 3 will swap position with No. 2 "],
         ["No. 4 will swap position with No. 7 and No. 7 will swap position with No.6 and 
           No. 6 will swap position with No. 5 and No. 5 will swap position with No.4"]]
```

Does anyone help me to do with my task with python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you have three layers per element of the given list: (1) handle multiple lists, `"or ".join()` the results (2) handle a list of `n` items, `" and ".join()` the `n-1` results from circular pairs and (3) handle a pair of values giving the basic text decription.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just wanna `rotate` the `inner list` by `1`. For which you can use `deque`:

```
from collections import deque

result = []
for i in l:
    temp = []
    for index,j in enumerate(i):
        j = deque(j)
        if index == 0: # instead of using 0 you can use random number within the range 
            j.rotate(1) # you can provide the custom number if required.
        temp.append(j)
    result.append(temp)
```